# StartSSL certificate on domain and subdomain + two different servers

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

I have created free StartSSL certificate (class 1, https://www.startssl.com/?app=1) for **www.example.com** which is also valid on subdomain **dev.example.com**.

Can I use this certificate, if www.example.com is on server 1 and dev.example.com on the second server? I'm using Apache.

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have both `www.example.com` and `dev.example.com` on a a Class 1 certificate. The Class 1 certificate is only valid for the base domain (`example.com`) and a single subdomain (`dev.example.com`).

To have valid SSL certs for both `www.example.com` and `dev.example.com`, you'll need to create multiple certificates or upgrade to Class 2 certificates. If the domains are on different IP addresses, either solution is fine. If you're sharing an IP address, multiple SSL certificates will only work properly for modern browsers that support [Server Name Indication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication).

See also:

- [38.) How can I use the same certificate on multiple servers?](https://www.startssl.com/?app=25#38)

Comment: A note, "Class 1/2/etc." is marketing BS from Verisign and a few other vendors, as far as I can tell. They have no real meaning.

Comment: @ceejayoz As far as I can see, a higher class means that the identity has been checked more thoroughly. The only difference it makes for the resulting certificates is that they are signed from a different intermediate cert. Other than that, the certificates are equal (perhaps with an extra Organization field in the DN, but that [does not really add extra value](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/35076/2630)).

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't be a problem from the technical point of view.

I have no idea if this is ok according to the license.

Answer (score 0):

On [this website](http://wiki.stocksy.co.uk/wiki/Using_StartCom_%28StartSSL%29_to_Generate_valid_SSL_Certificates) you will learn how to create your own Private Key, then send to startssl to certificate your subdomains.

Doing this, you will be using the same CSR for all your subdomains.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Generally we like answers on the site to be able to stand on their own - Links are great, but if that link ever breaks the answer should have enough information to still be helpful. Please consider editing your answer to include more detail. See the [FAQ](http://www.serverfault.com/faq) for more info.